# Count rows with multiple parameters in an Array formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want a count of all rows that are in the month of June and have NOT paid.

I have data as follows:

```
Type    Date        Invoice #   Customer    Memo    Date Due    Amt Chrg
Invoice  6/1/2018   1234         Name123             PAID        32.50
Invoice  6/7/2018   1235         Name12              7/22/18     12.30
Invoice  6/3/2018   1236         Name1               PAID        52.82
Invoice  7/1/2018   1237         Name                7/22/18     631.50
Invoice  8/1/2018   1238         Name213             PAID        236.20
Invoice  7/1/2018   1239         Name223             PAID        3.10
Invoice  7/5/2018   1240         Name323             PAID        16.60
```

My formula to calculate the count is below.  Excel outputs: total rows - the count of invoices that are in June and HAVE NOT paid.

```
{=COUNT(IF((MONTH(ARRegister!$B$2:$B$1275)=6)*(ARRegister!$F$2:$F$1275<>"Paid"),ARRegister!$A$2:$A$1275,0))}
```

How do I correct my formula so the count is output rather than total rows minus my count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Date is in column B and Date Due is in column F, consider the following formula:
`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B2:B1275)=6)*(F2:F1275<>"Paid"))`

`SUMPRODUCT()`, as the name goes, "sums" the "product" of arrays within it. So basically, it works with arrays, but doesn't need to be returned using the `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER` combination.

The 'double negative' "--" is a trick to change TRUE/FALSE values into 1/0, which is then multiplied together and summed up.

Comment: Good answer, but note that everything inside the `SUMPRODUCT` argument is automatically an array formula, even though you don't enter it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, yep that's correct. I should have worded my statement in there more accurately. Let me insert a `SUMPRODUCT` description in there.

Comment: It was more just an FYI for you in case you didn't know. Anyway, good answer. +1.

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be an array formula? You could count the rows in month 6 then minus the ones which are month 6 and paid like so:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,6)-COUNTIFS(B:B,6,F:F,"Paid")
```

Comment: This doesn't work, theres no month function for 6 to be compared against?

Comment: The `B` column is a date, not a month.

Comment: Ahhh I missed that, you could use a helper column or continue with an array formula.